# hide component when root path is found in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, react-router-dom

I have import `withRouter` using

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

in my `App.js` file is like:

```
const App = (props) => {

    const { location } = props;

    return (

      <Router>
       <>
          {location.pathname!=='/' && <Navbar />}
      
      
         <Switch>
           <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
           <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
           <Route path="/sale" component={Sale} />
           <Route path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
         </Switch>
       </>
     </Router>
   );
  }
```

export default withRouter(App);

But it is not working.

I want when root (`/`) path is found `<Navbar />` component will hide. it will show when other paths found. But hide only in root path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a layout component

```
const Layout = ({children, showNavbar = true}) => {

  return (
    <>
      {showNavbar && <NavBar />}
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

In your home and other component

```
const Home = () => {
   return (
     <Layout showNavbar={false}>
       // Your home component
     <Layout />
  )
}


const OtherComponent = () => {
   return (
     <Layout>
       // Your other component
     <Layout />
  )
}
```

Your router

```
<Router>
       <>
         <Switch>
           <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
           <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
           <Route path="/sale" component={Sale} />
           <Route path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
         </Switch>
       </>
</Router>
```

Comment: is this need that use Layout to all components?? or only use when navbar show?

Comment: You can use both way. I prefer in all component. Just pass the porps to hide the navbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use useLocation

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Sale from './pages/Sale';
import Accounts from './pages/Accounts';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';


const App = () => {

  const locationObj = useLocation()

    return (
        <>
          {locationObj.pathname !== '/' ? <Navbar /> : null}
          
          
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/sale" component={Sale} />
            <Route path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
          </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Don't forget to put your Router inside index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: not working for me: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

Comment: Did you put BrowserRouter/Router inside index.js

Comment: Sorry put your BrowserRouter/Router inside index.js I updated my answer.

Comment: yes i put inside index.js but it also hide from all the components

Comment: it works but facing some problem thanks for your help. another answer is perfectly works for me.